# sshd is running, but cannot connect

Tags: debian, sshd

I have a remote dedicated server.  It is running the newest Debian stable.  Having had it running for quite a while, I finally decided to reboot it so it could run on a newer kernel.  However, since rebooting, I have been unable to connect via ports 22, 80 and 443.  The server responds to ping.  SSH error message: `Connection timed out`.

Fortunately, the data centre where it is located has a rescue system, that I have used - albeit in vain - to fix this problem.  After looking through `syslog` and `auth.log`, it is clear that `sshd` is started by `systemd` correctly, and appears to be listening on port 22 as expected.

```
Mar  3 09:28:48 server sshd[975]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Mar  3 09:33:55 server sshd[975]: Received signal 15; terminating.
```

Yet somehow, I am unable to access it remotely.  Most issues I look for of this sort are about `sshd` not starting at all, but that does not appear to be the case.  I am able to access the rescue system without problem remotely, so the issue is not on my end.  I wonder if there are perhaps some firewall services, that I am unaware of that might have been installed.  Or some `sshd` settings to be wary of.

For the record, here is my `sshd_config` with all comments removed:

```
Port 22

ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

LoginGraceTime 120

PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes

HostbasedAuthentication no

PermitEmptyPasswords no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

PasswordAuthentication no

PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

UsePAM yes
UseDNS no
```

Since it also appears to be a problem for port 80 and 443, I wonder whether it is a more general problem, but at least if I could get SSH to work, I would be able to perhaps fix those problems as well.

Comment: Use IP KVM to figure out what's really going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
sudo ufw allow 22
```

See also:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/30080/how-to-solve-connection-refused-errors-in-ssh-connection

Comment: You nailed it with the `ufw` suggestion.  It was indeed that blocking the ports.  Using the KVM suggestion in comment to my question, I was able to permit port 22.  And now I can access it, permitting the other two blocked ports.

Comment: It's weird a reboot enabled a firewall. I guess it's down to Debian peculiarities.